# CMake cant find Boost, installed with vcpkg

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, vcpkg

CMake can't find Boost, installed with vcpkg

CMakeLists in my project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(my_project)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE /home/xander/.local/bin/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem system)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Create the executable target
add_executable(my_executable test.cpp)

# Link the Boost libraries to the target
target_link_libraries(my_executable PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

CMakeBuild provides an error:

```
|| CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
||   Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR filesystem system)
|| Call Stack (most recent call first):
||   /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
||   /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2377 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
||   CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
|| 
|| 
|| -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
|| Exited with code 1
```

Lib is installed:

```
[xander]% cd .local/bin/vcpkg
[archhater:vcpkg] on master
[xander]% ./vcpkg list
...
boost-accumulators:x64-linux                      1.81.0#2            Boost accumulators module
boost-algorithm:x64-linux                         1.81.0#2            Boost algorithm module
boost-align:x64-linux                             1.81.0#2            Boost align module
boost-any:x64-linux                               1.81.0#2            Boost any module
etc
...
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Setting `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` variable after the `project()` call is useless. Instead, pass this variable to `cmake` with `-D` option.

Comment: move the command `set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE /home/xander/.local/bin/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)` before `project()` command.